# При смене ориентации экрана приложение падает, почему такое?

Tags: android

Я запускаю свое приложение (в моем случае на планшете) держу в "портретной" ориентации, поворачиваю экран - приложение падает. Запускаю это же приложение в "альбомной" ориентации, работает, поворачиваю на "портретную" - падает. Почему так происходит?

Comment: ошибка в 3 строке.

По факту - при переворачивании повторно вызывается метод onCreate. Если в коде активити создали объект и надеетесь что он переживет поворот, то будет падение.

В целом, показывайте код.

Comment: Без стектрейса тут никак - выкладывайте стектрейс падения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы забываете сохранять состояние в `onSaveInstanceState` (и, соответственно, восстанавливать его в `onCreate`) и, как следствие, получаете `NullPointerException`. Не забывайте, что при изменении ориентации устройства `Activity` пересоздаётся.

Для более точного диагноза нужен стектрейс исключения.

Comment: Спасибо. Я выключила в манифесте. 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" 
Больше не падает.